# Short tags on, but code not executing

Tags: php, apache

Let me say right up front that I don't want this to become a discussion of whether you should use short tags or not. I am trying to get a legacy system running, it has thousands of files of php code, and changing them all without getting any errors is not a solution we want to use.

That being said, I have short tags enabled in php.ini. I have verified that the setting is taking effect by running `phpinfo();` in the file in question and checking the setting there. However, code inside the `<?` or `<?=` short open tags is not being executed, it is only printing out as if it was HTML. Anybody know a reason why this could possibly happen? PHP code inside the normal `<?PHP` open tags is being executed normally. Originally the server was running PHP 5.3, we tried upgrading to 5.4.7 due to the changes in short tags in 5.4, and still no luck.

To repeat what was in the comments: I ran `phpinfo()` by adding it into a file that uses both short and normal open tags and opening it in a browser. Full tags executed, short did not. I did not run it from the command line. Apache was restarted. The php.ini file edited was the main /etc/php.ini file. There is no .htaccess file changing the setting in the webroot.

Comment: Did you try `<?` and `<?php` in the same exact file?

Comment: Did you check `phpinfo()` from the command line? Command line and apache module PHP may use different `php.ini` files. Also, do short open tags work wherever it is that you are doing `phpinfo()` from?

Comment: Are you on a shared host? Sometimes they have a "Master" php.ini that cannot be overriden by a local one in some directives. Also, CLI has a php.ini on its own, you might be modifiying the wrong one

Comment: It's not a local php.ini, it is the master one. I have full control of the server. `phpinfo()` was added into the php file and run. i have tried both tags, the full one works the short does not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restarted the web server after changing the php.ini file? you must do it for the setting to take effect..

Comment: Yes, the server was restarted. That can be further verified by the `phpinfo()` placed in the file returning the proper value for the short tags.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems unchecked is that the value from the ini file is being overwritten somewhere.

Perhaps an overzealous developer disabled it in an .htaccess file, with `ini_set()` or [somewhere else](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)?

Comment: I've checked that as well - no .htaccess file is setting it either way, and I even tried `ini_set()` myself, forcing it.